# Why do I receive null object from laravel API?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

In reactjs using axios when i send a get request to laravel api i receive a null object but i receive data in Insomnia api tester.

Here is my react js code:

```
class EditStudent extends Component {

state = {
    name: '',
    course: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
}

handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }); 
    
}

async componentDidMount(){
    const std_id = this.props.match.id;
    const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/edit-student/${std_id}`);
    console.log(result); //the answer I receive comes null

    
}
```

My api controller:

```
public function edit($id){
    
    $student = Student::find($id);
    $student = $student;
    return response()->json([
        "status" => 200,
        "student" => $student,
    ]);
}
```

I have also installed fruitcake for laravel CORS issue.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's network console to see if the request is getting made and and response you're getting?

Comment: Yes, i did check that, it is kind of strange if i set the $student = 123;  manually in laravel api edit function,  i will receive data in reactjs(axios) but when proceeding like upper way i get a null object but with correct status code 200.

Comment: is the entire response `null` or do you get something like `{ status: 200, student: null }`?

Comment: I get { status: 200, student: null } this